# Changing the value of a variable that is of type factor in R

Tags: r

In R, when I have a variable of type factor, then I can only update values within the specified factor levels.  As a simple example:

```
LowerCourt = factor(x=c("conser", "liberal"), levels=c("conser", "liberal"))
> LowerCourt
[1] conser  liberal
Levels: conser liberal
```

Thus, the following is permissible:

```
LowerCourt[1] <- "liberal"
> LowerCourt
[1] liberal liberal
Levels: conser liberal
```

But the following is not allowed since the reset value is outside the specified levels:

```
LowerCourt[1] <- "libera"
```

However, this scheme falls apart with a factor of size one like so:

```
LowerCourt = factor(x="conser", levels=c("conser", "liberal"))
LowerCourt <- "liberal"
```

The reassignment changes the type so that now `class(LowerCourt) == "character"`, defeating the purpose of using the factor type.  What I want is to reset the value within specified levels and retain the type.

I have encountered this situation with a list (say, `input`), the contents of which are factors (e.g. `input$LowerCourt`, `input$Petitioner`, etc.).  Any time I reset the value of a factor to one of the permissible levels, the value changes but so does the type (to character).  This breaks some other code that expects the correct types.

I'd appreciate any guidance to work around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about length of `factor`, you are actually over-riding the previous value by assigning new value to the variable `LowerCourt`.

If you change only the first value as in your first example, `LowerCourt` would still remain as `factor`

```
LowerCourt[1] <- "liberal"
LowerCourt
#[1] liberal
#Levels: conser liberal
```

Moreover, even if the factor variable is of length more than one but if you override the value it get's turned into character.

```
LowerCourt = factor(x=c("conser", "liberal"), levels=c("conser", "liberal"))
LowerCourt <- "liberal"
LowerCourt
#[1] "liberal"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-assigning the variable as 'liberal' which is a character and not a factor. So, your class changes.

Either re-define the variable with `factor(x=c("liberal"),levels=c("conser","liberal"))`

OR if you want entire vector replaced with the value use:

```
LowerCourt1 = factor(x=rep("liberal",length(LowerCourt)),levels=c("conser","liberal"))
```

Let me know if this works.